# Trigger periodic celery task after an event

Tags: python-3.x, celery, scheduled-tasks, celerybeat

I'm using celery to manage tasks. Need to initiate the periodic task(which runs every 5 minutes) only if the first `regular task` is triggered, has to run every minute and should stop if all other regular tasks completed. Is there a way that can help this one!

> Here is my celery beat schedule in settings.py

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'celery-periodic-task': {
        'task': 'task.add',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1')
    }
}
```